# Booting Win8 in safe mode without recovery CD

Tags: windows-8, boot, drivers, bsod, safe-mode

I'm running an Acer Aspire V5-573G running windows 8. I was trying to update the thing, and after updating some drivers, the machine no longer boots to the operating system but just instead does a black screen for a while and then the blue screen of death showing error code "DRIVER POWER STATE FAILURE"

I understand that this is a driver issue, and I need to rollback my driver update. I also understand that I'll need to do this by booting into safe mode since normal booting only gets me the blue screen of death. The part I'm having trouble with is that f8 and shift-f8 booting into safe mode has been disabled since it's windows 8, there's no cd drive for a recovery disk, and I have no access to another win8 machine to make a recovery flash drive.

In this kind of situation, how might I still enable/boot in safe mode so that I could fix this driver issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to another computer (not necessarily Windows 8 based), I would suggest getting an official Windows 8 ISO and making a bootable USB thumb drive from it. Once you boot into the installer disc on your computer, from the main menu, select "Repair your computer." From the following menu, navigate to Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Command Prompt. Here, you can edit your boot configuration data (BCD) to enable booting Safe Mode in the traditional manner (F8) from older versions of Windows.

Simply execute the following:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

Although my experience with repairing BCDs for Windows 7 systems would suggest otherwise, you may need to specify the location of your BCD store in this command. [This reference page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx) from Microsoft may be helpful.

Once you've made the change, you can then try booting into Safe Mode and do what you need to do to get your computer back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Setting only boot menu policy would not help much on a fast computer when you have only one boot entry.

A second boot entry would help - you can add recovery entry to boot menu for example using

```
bcdedit /displayorder {GUID} /addlast
```

where {GUID} is id of recovery loader.

You can view id's of all loaders using "bcdedit /enum ALL /v".

Setting boot timeout to a greater value - for example 15 (15 sec.) would also be useful.

```
bcdedit /timeout 15
```